# Why can I change the the reserved blocks on a read only mounted ext4 filesystem?

Tags: linux, ext4, ubuntu-20.04, read-only

I would have expected an error, sorry FS is read-only, but it is possible. This is unexpected & counter intuitive is there a reason?

```
Linux files 5.11.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 11 15:58:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
files@files:/mnt/disk$ mount | grep /mnt/disk/005
/dev/sdh on /mnt/disk/005 type ext4 (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user)
files@files:/mnt/disk$ df /mnt/disk/005/
Filesystem      1K-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdh       7751367424 7332824836  27824876 100% /mnt/disk/005
files@files:/mnt/disk$ sudo tune2fs -r 0 /dev/sdh
tune2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Setting reserved blocks count to 0
files@files:/mnt/disk$ df /mnt/disk/005/
Filesystem      1K-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdh       7751367424 7332824836 418526204  95% /mnt/disk/005
files@files:/mnt/disk$
```

Answer (score 10):

`tune2fs` never needed the filesystem to be mounted to operate. As you can see in the command, you pass a block device node (`/dev/sdh`) as an argument to it, not a mountpoint (`/mnt/disk/005`). It's similar to `resize2fs` and `e2label`.

Comment: While the read-only restriction on the *mount* has no effect here, Linux *block devices* could be marked as read-only in a similar fashion, e.g. `blockdev --setro /dev/example` restricts (future) access to the device and/or partition in question.

Comment: @anx AFAIK, that may not be something that is really reliable. (I've never really digged deep into how it works, but IIRC I've seen stories about it being unexpectedly "breakable".)

Comment: True. Propagation through partitions/md/rbd etc seems mostly reasonable these days, it just remains one of those little known, little used features that barely even get bugs reported.